# Python: Merge two CSV files to multilevel JSON

Tags: python, json, csv

I am very new to Python/JSON so please bear with me on this. I could do this in R but we need to use Python so as to transform this to Python/Spark/MongoDB. Also, I am just posting a minimal subset - I have a couple more file types and so if anyone can help me with this, I can build upon that to integrate more files and file types:

Getting back to my problem:

I have two tsv input files that I need to merge and convert to JSON. Both the files have gene and sample columns plus some additional columns. However, the `gene` and `sample` may or may not overlap like I have shown - f2.tsv has all genes in f1.tsv but also has an additional gene `g3`. Similarly, both files have overlapping as well as non-overlapping values in `sample` column.

```
# f1.tsv – has gene, sample and additional column other1

$ cat f1.tsv 
gene    sample  other1
g1      s1      a1
g1      s2      b1
g1      s3a     c1
g2      s4      d1

# f2.tsv – has gene, sample and additional columns other21, other22

$ cat f2.tsv 
gene    sample  other21 other22
g1      s1      a21     a22
g1      s2      b21     b22
g1      s3b     c21     c22
g2      s4      d21     d22
g3      s5      f21     f22
```

*The gene forms the top level, each gene has multiple samples which form the second level and the additional columns form the `extras` which is the third level.* The extras are divided into two because one file has `other1` and the second file has `other21` and `other22`. The other files that I will include later will have other fields like `other31` and `other32` and so on but they will still have the gene and sample columns.

```
# expected output – JSON by combining both tsv files. 
$ cat output.json 
[{
  "gene":"g1",
  "samples":[
    {
      "sample":"s2",
      "extras":[
        {
          "other1":"b1"
        },
        {
          "other21":"b21",
          "other22":"b22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample":"s1",
      "extras":[
        {
          "other1":"a1"
        },
        {
          "other21":"a21",
          "other22":"a22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample":"s3b",
      "extras":[
        {
          "other21":"c21",
          "other22":"c22"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "sample":"s3a",
      "extras":[
        {
          "other1":"c1"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},{
  "gene":"g2",
  "samples":[
    {
      "sample":"s4",
      "extras":[
        {
          "other1":"d1"
        },
        {
          "other21":"d21",
          "other22":"d22"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},{
  "gene":"g3",
  "samples":[
    {
      "sample":"s5",
      "extras":[
        {
          "other21":"f21",
          "other22":"f22"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

How do convert two csv files to a single - multi level JSON based on two common columns?

I would really appreciate any help that I can get on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another option.  I tried to make it easy to manage when you start adding more files.  You can run on the command line and provide arguments, one for each file you want to add in.  Gene/sample names are stored in dictionaries to improve efficiency.  The formatting of your desired JSON object is done in each class' format() method.  Hope this helps.

```
import csv, json, sys

class Sample(object):
    def __init__(self, name, extras):
        self.name = name
        self.extras = [extras]

    def format(self):
        map = {}
        map['sample'] = self.name
        map['extras'] = self.extras
        return map

    def add_extras(self, extras):
        #edit 8/20
        #always just add the new extras to the list
        for extra in extras:
            self.extras.append(extra)

class Gene(object):
    def __init__(self, name, samples):
        self.name = name
        self.samples = samples

    def format(self):
        map = {}
        map ['gene'] = self.name
        map['samples'] = sorted([self.samples[sample_key].format() for sample_key in self.samples], key=lambda sample: sample['sample'])
        return map

    def create_or_add_samples(self, new_samples):
        # loop through new samples, seeing if they already exist in the gene object
        for sample_name in new_samples:
            sample = new_samples[sample_name]
            if sample.name in self.samples:
                self.samples[sample.name].add_extras(sample.extras)
            else:
                self.samples[sample.name] = sample

class Genes(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.genes = {}

    def format(self):
        return sorted([self.genes[gene_name].format() for gene_name in self.genes], key=lambda gene: gene['gene'])

    def create_or_add_gene(self, gene):
        if not gene.name in self.genes:
            self.genes[gene.name] = gene
        else:
            self.genes[gene.name].create_or_add_samples(gene.samples)

def row_to_gene(headers, row):
    gene_name = ""
    sample_name = ""
    extras = {}
    for value in enumerate(row):
        if headers[value[0]] == "gene":
            gene_name = value[1]
        elif headers[value[0]] == "sample":
            sample_name = value[1]
        else:
            extras[headers[value[0]]] = value[1]
    sample_dict = {}
    sample_dict[sample_name] = Sample(sample_name, extras)
    return Gene(gene_name, sample_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    delim = "\t"
    genes = Genes()
    files = sys.argv[1:]

    for file in files:
        print("Reading " + str(file))
        with open(file,'r') as f1:
            reader = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=delim)
            headers = []
            for row in reader:
                if len(headers) == 0:
                    headers = row
                else:
                    genes.create_or_add_gene(row_to_gene(headers, row))

    result = json.dumps(genes.format(), indent=4)
    print(result)
    with open('json_output.txt', 'w') as output:
        output.write(result)
```

Comment: It works great - I really love that you have it so generalized - where I can specify the delimiter as well as any number of files. This is incredible!

Comment: I just have one problem - For g1/s1 it shows ```"extras": [
                    {
                        "other1": "a1"
                    }, 
                    [
                        {
                            "other22": "a22", 
                            "other21": "a21"
                        }
                    ]
                ]``` I want to remove the inner square brackets from extras.

Comment: @KomalRathi oops, sorry about that. I edited with the fix

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a problem for `pandas`! Unfortunately pandas only takes us so far and we then have to do some manipulation on our own. This is neither fast nor particularly efficient code, but it will get the job done.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from collections import defaultdict

# here we import the tsv files as pandas df
f1 = pd.read_table('f1.tsv', delim_whitespace=True)
f2 = pd.read_table('f2.tsv', delim_whitespace=True)

# we then let pandas merge them
newframe = f1.merge(f2, how='outer', on=['gene', 'sample'])

# have pandas write them out to a json, and then read them back in as a
# python object (a list of dicts)
pythonList = json.loads(newframe.to_json(orient='records'))


newDict = {}
for d in pythonList:
    gene = d['gene']
    sample = d['sample']
    sampleDict = {'sample':sample,
                  'extras':[]}

    extrasdict = defaultdict(lambda:dict())

    if gene not in newDict:
        newDict[gene] = {'gene':gene, 'samples':[]}

    for key, value in d.iteritems():
        if 'other' not in key or value is None:
            continue
        else:
            id = key.split('other')[-1]
            if len(id) == 1:
                extrasdict['1'][key] = value
            else:
                extrasdict['{}'.format(id[0])][key] = value

    for value in extrasdict.values():
        sampleDict['extras'].append(value)

    newDict[gene]['samples'].append(sampleDict)

newList = [v for k, v in newDict.iteritems()]

print json.dumps(newList)
```

If this looks like a solution that will work for you, I am happy to spend some time cleaning it up to make it bait more readable and efficient.

PS: If you like R, then pandas is the way to go (it was written to give a R-like interface to data in python)

Comment: This solution is perfect! I just accepted gregbert's answer because his code has the functionality to specify as many input files and the delimiter. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in steps:

1. Read the incoming `tsv` files and aggregate the information from different genes into a dictionary.
2. Process said dictionary to match your desired format.
3. Write the result to a JSON file.

Here is the code:

```
import csv
import json
from collections import defaultdict

input_files = ['f1.tsv', 'f2.tsv']
output_file = 'genes.json'

# Step 1
gene_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
for file in input_files:
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for line in reader:
            gene = line.pop('gene')
            sample = line.pop('sample')
            gene_dict[gene][sample].append(line)

# Step 2
out = [{'gene': gene,
        'samples': [{'sample': sample, 'extras': extras}
                    for sample, extras in samples.items()]}
       for gene, samples in gene_dict.items()]

# Step 3
with open(output_file, 'w') as f:
    json.dump(out, f)
```

Comment: This solution is perfect! I just accepted gregbert's answer because his code has the functionality to specify as many input files and the delimiter. Thank you very much.

Comment: Notice that those are also very easy to do with my code: to add more input files, append their names to the `input_files` list; to change the delimiter, edit line 12.